# Not able to view the Stack Trace console in eclipse Version: 3.2.1 .

Tags: java, eclipse, stack, stack-trace

Please help me out and forgive me if this is a really stupid question .

I am not able to view the Stack Trace console in eclipse . I have opened the console window and it appears at the bottom part of the window . I have tried changing to Java Stack Trace console using the funky "+ window" button in the console window from the CVC console but still it sticks to the CVS Console . Thus I am not able to view the stack trace for my console program .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Trace console is designed for pasting in stack traces by hand, not for showing stack trace output from a running program. You need the normal console for your application (try Ctrl-3, then type 'Console - General').

Also, Eclipse 3.2.1 is ancient, so you should try to upgrade.